# setting the MGF hash to a different value other than the regular hash with openssl for PSS signatures

Tags: rsa, signature, openssl, pkcs11, probabilistic-encryption

In [PKCS1's Probabilistic Signature Mode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-9.1.1) you have the Hash and the MGF Hash. Both appear to be, by default, sha1, with the OpenSSL CLI client, however, I can change it to sha256 with the following:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -out signature.txt -sign privatekey.txt plaintext.txt
```

What if I wanted to have the Hash be sha256 and the MGF Hash by sha1? Is that possible? I just wonder because with Java the default mode for OAEP encryption changes the hash but [not the MGF hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32161720/569976) (thus making them disjoint)

Answer (score 6):

Meta: since this is about using a tool not the underlying algorithm/math AIUI should be security.SE instead. If anyone can and wants to migrate feel free.

Per 1.0.2 source, `-sigopt rsa_mgf1_md:name` where `name` is the name of a hash available to `EVP_getdigestbyname` -- that is, implemented and not #if'ed out by default (MD2) nor manually.

For FIPS mode if relevant, I *think* you can *set* a non-FIPS hash but then the operation using it will fail, but I don't have a FIPS build set up to test.